# Match exact values in cells in different sheets with multiple values that are similar?

Tags: microsoft-word, worksheet-function

I know similar questions have been asked before, I have either not found sufficient information how to solve it or it uses VBA which I would like to avoid (since I don't understand it well enough to modify or understand how it works, if I need to update it in the future).

I have three excel sheets that combine into the output data that I need. How they are structured:

**Sheet 1**

```
ID    Unique Name
1     Melon
2     Melon seedless
3     Melon yellow
4     Apple
```

**Sheet 2**

```
SKU    Dimension
A      Round
A S    Round
A Y    Round
C      Round
```

**Sheet 3**

```
SKU           Group Name
A, A S, A Y   Melon's
C             Apples
```

I was using this formula to find and match the value's of the ID's and SKU's.

`=INDEX('DEV_ID''s'!A:A;MATCH(INDEX(Variables!H:H;MATCH("*"&AA!C2&"*";Variables!C:C;0));'DEV_ID''s'!B:B;0))`

The main issue is the first part of the formula: `"*"&AA!C2&"*"` Where I match the SKU from Sheet 2 with the SKU group in Sheet 3.

The problem is that my SKU's in Sheet 3 can have either 1 or multipel values, theres not always a comma delimiter. I'm not sure how to both look for space and comma at the same time to make sure `A S` and `A Y` is not matched with only `A`.

Any ideas how I can make this match?

Comment: So, after reading some more excel how-to's the formula works if i re-arrange my rows of data. As long as `Melon seedless` is *above* `Melon` I wont get the issue. Seems like a work around since you cant always control the sorting of your data, but it works for now.